# correct pattern for dask compute minimum?

Tags: python, dask

Is this the correct way to call `compute()`?

```
def call_minmax_duration(data):
    mmin = dd.DataFrame.min(data).compute()
    mmax = dd.DataFrame.max(data).compute()
    return mmin, mmax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things.

Your `data` variable should be a dask.dataframe object, such as might be created by `dd.from_pandas(...)` or `dd.read_csv(...)`

Second, it's probably better to compute both results at once that way shared intermediates only need to be computed once

#### Example

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('2016-*-*.csv')

dd.compute(df.mycolumn.min(), df.mycolumn.max())
```